# Crash logs indicated app crashes on UIPopoverPresentationController method not present in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit, crash-reports

I am receiving crash logs that say that my app is crashing on `[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin]`, but nowhere in my code do I use a UIPopoverPresentationController.  The've all been on iPads, I use a UIDocumentInteractionController which seems similar, maybe It's a subclass of UIPopoverPresentationController, I don't know.  Any idea what could be causing this?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x184799900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x183e07f80 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:531)
2   UIKit                           0x189db43a0 -[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 2884 (UIPopoverPresentationController.m:1197)
3   UIKit                           0x1897e82fc __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 1640 (UIPresentationController.m:1136)
4   UIKit                           0x1897e6414 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 332 (UIPresentationController.m:704)
5   UIKit                           0x18973cb70 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292 (UIApplication.m:2312)
6   UIKit                           0x18974a030 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 92 (UIApplication.m:2290)
7   UIKit                           0x18947dc24 _afterCACommitHandler + 96 (UIApplication.m:2342)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x184750588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1620)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18474e32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:1716)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x18474e75c __CFRunLoopRun + 928 (CFRunLoop.c:2558)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18467d680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
12  GraphicsServices                0x185b8c088 GSEventRunModal + 180 (GSEvent.c:2245)
13  UIKit                           0x1894f4d90 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3681)
14  MyCoolApp                       0x100083564 0x10007c000 + 30052
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x18421e8b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:80)
```

Comment: This is related to 3D touch on iPhone 6s devices. Really unfortunate, since as far as I can tell, there's no way to prevent it from happening. I've been getting similar reports out of Fabric.io for an app of mine.

Comment: I'm only getting it on iPads.  Are your users telling you anything?

Comment: Yeah, sorry should have clarified - it's not related to the 3D touch event, it's related to iOS 9's code that handles 3D touch. No details from any users yet unfortunately.

Comment: I have one from an iOS 8.2 user.  How did you figure out that it was iOS 9 or 3D related?

Comment: Whoa seriously? OK news to me then. I had read some log dumps and some people relating `UIPopoverPresentationController` to 3D touch. Looks like it's back to the drawing board!

Comment: @remus The problem for me was presenting a UIAlertController action sheet with presentViewController instead of using it's popoverPresentationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem ended up being that I had a UIAlertController that I was presenting the wrong way. Here's what caused the crash.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NULL message:NULL preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:copyKey style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:alerAction]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:shareKey style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:alerAction]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelKey style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:alerAction]];

//THIS LINE CRASHED IT
[self presentViewController:alert animated:1 completion:NULL];
```

I just hadn't done adequate testing on the iPad,  When the I tried this with the debugger plugged in it crashed and gave me a lengthy useful message, here's an excerpt "You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController". So this is how I present it now and It works.

```
[alert setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alert popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView = self.view;
popPresenter.sourceRect = alertSourceRect;
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```